# R: Split and aggregate factor variable into several subgroups

Tags: split, aggregate, subset

I have a repeated-measure data-set where I have one factor variable with several values. I would like to aggregate this data-set in such a way that 4 values of this factor variable are aggregated into 2.

The raw data-set looks something like this:

```
ID condition side value
01 B left 13
01 C left 20
01 A left 9
01 D left 23
01 A right 11
01 B right 17
01 C right 18
01 D right 7
02 B left 12
02 A right 11


etc.
```

I know how to aggregate this data-set in such a way that condition A-D are aggregated into one variable and the sum of value is calculated. I code this as followed:

```
subset <- Data %>%
group_by(ID, side) %>%
summarise(
condition = toString(condition),
value = sum(value)
)
```

The output looks something like this:

```
ID side condition value
01 left B,C,A,D 65
01 right A,B,C,D 53
```

But what I do not want to aggregate all conditions (A-D) into one variable and calculate the value sum based on this. I would split condition into 2 parts (A+B & C+D) and calculate the value sum based on this. Thus, the subset I would like to get in the end should look something like this:

```
ID side condition value
01 left B,A 22
01 left C,D 43
01 right A,B 28
01 right C,D 25
```

Has anyone an idea what I should change in my code in order to accomplish this?

Thank you in advance!